# React Component Warning setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs, redux, setstate

I'm trying to display a countdown timer using the following Component code But I keep getting the Warning.

> "Warning setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component"

However, I assumed I was only setting state after checking if my isMounted state variable was true throughout the component. Where is my mistake?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

export default class CountDownTimerContainer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    initialTimeRemaining: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    interval: PropTypes.number,
    formatFunc: PropTypes.func,
    tickCallback: PropTypes.func,
    completeCallback: PropTypes.func
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      timeRemaining: this.props.initialTimeRemaining,
      timeoutId: null,
      prevTime: null,
      isMounted: false
    }
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.setState({isMounted: true})
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.tick()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps (newProps) {
    if (this.state.timeoutId) {
      clearTimeout(this.state.timeoutId)
    }
    if (this.state.isMounted) {
      this.setState({prevTime: null, timeRemaining: newProps.initialTimeRemaining})
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate () {
    if ((!this.state.prevTime) && this.state.timeRemaining > 0 && this.state.isMounted) {
      this.tick().bind(this)
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.setState({isMounted: false})
    clearTimeout(this.state.timeoutId)
  }

  tick () {
    const currentTime = Date.now()
    const dt = this.state.prevTime ? (currentTime - this.state.prevTime) : 0
    const interval = this.props.interval

    // correct for small variations in actual timeout time
    const timeRemainingInInterval = (interval - (dt % interval))
    let timeout = timeRemainingInInterval

    if (timeRemainingInInterval < (interval / 2.0)) {
      timeout += interval
    }

    const timeRemaining = Math.max(this.state.timeRemaining - dt, 0)
    const countdownComplete = (this.state.prevTime && timeRemaining <= 0)

    if (this.state.isMounted) {
      if (this.state.timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(this.state.timeoutId)
      }
      this.setState({
        timeoutId: countdownComplete ? null : setTimeout(this.tick.bind(this), timeout),
        prevTime: currentTime,
        timeRemaining: timeRemaining
      })
    }

    if (countdownComplete) {
      if (this.props.completeCallback) {
        this.props.completeCallback()
      }
      return
    }

    if (this.props.tickCallback) {
      this.props.tickCallback(timeRemaining)
    }
  }

  getFormattedTime (milliseconds) {
    if (this.props.formatFunc) {
      return this.props.formatFunc(milliseconds)
    }

    var totalSeconds = Math.round(milliseconds / 1000)

    var seconds = parseInt(totalSeconds % 60, 10)
    var minutes = parseInt(totalSeconds / 60, 10) % 60
    var hours = parseInt(totalSeconds / 3600, 10)

    seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes
    hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours

    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds
  }

  render () {
    var timeRemaining = this.state.timeRemaining
    return (
      <div className='timer'>
        {this.getFormattedTime(timeRemaining)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

CountDownTimerContainer.defaultProps = {
  interval: 1000,
  formatFunc: null,
  tickCallback: null,
  completeCallback: null
}
```

**Update:** Even after removing

```
this.setState({isMounted: true})
```

from ComponentWIllMount and adding it to the constructor as `this.state({isMounted: true})` I still get the setStateError.

Comment: On which call of the four to `setState` does it happen?

Comment: Well it tells you what is wrong I think:

you use `setState` in `componentWillMount` when the component hasn't yet been mounted. I question your need to set the state there in the first place.

Comment: move it to componentDidMount

Comment: moving the setState to componentDidMount() stops the counter from working And I get the lint error that Do not use setState in componentDidMount. And Event if I remove this.setState({isMounted: true}) I still get the error

Answer (score 1):

You quite literally do a `.setState()` before the component is mounting (`componentWillMount()`). You can't do that because the component doesn't exist yet. Rather put that in the `constructor()` as the initial state.

Comment: moving the setState to componentDidMount() stops the counter from working And I get the lint error that Do not use setState in componentDidMount

Comment: Yea, sorry, put that in `constructor()` as `this.state = {}`. That's the initial state.

Comment: Upon further testing I can't reproduce your issue: http://jsbin.com/wihizi/edit?js,output It is also not an anti-pattern to set the state in `componentDidMount`, so not sure why your linter doesn't like it.